# Complete list of Fonts which support

Tags: java, locale

Currently, if I change the locale setting of my application by

```
Locale.setDefault(Locale.ENGLISH);
```

[alt text http://sites.google.com/site/yanchengcheok/Home/Locale.ENGLISH.png](http://sites.google.com/site/yanchengcheok/Home/Locale.ENGLISH.png)

```
Locale.setDefault(Locale.SIMPLIFIED_CHINESE);
```

[alt text http://sites.google.com/site/yanchengcheok/Home/Locale.SIMPLIFIED_CHINESE.png](http://sites.google.com/site/yanchengcheok/Home/Locale.SIMPLIFIED_CHINESE.png)

What I understand from this [JFreeChart forum](http://www.jfree.org/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=27887&p=82686&hilit=chinese#p82686)  is that, I am not using correct font.

> Once you get the reference of the LegentTitle, you can set it to any font. Apparently, JFreeChart's default is "Tahoma" and it doesn't support Chinese characters.

May I know, how I can programmatic determine, as list of available Fonts in my system, which support Chinese?

I can hard code it to Serif (It fully support Chinese, doesn't it?), its look n feel doesn't looks good to me. I would like to have more choices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplified Chinese, which has thousands of glyphs, requires a Unicode font.

Here's a page of [simplified Chinese fonts](http://www.wazu.jp/gallery/Fonts_ChineseSimplified.html) I found through Google.

Comment: But, how I can make use of this font? and deploy to client?

Comment: Choose one of the fonts, download it, and put it in your CLASSPATH.  You'll have to package the font in your Jar and deliver it with your application, as your customers probably won't have the Chinese font you picked.